# Issue with ImagePullBackOff error in Kubernetes for React App

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, k8s-cluster-role

I am experiencing a problem with my deployment in Kubernetes, specifically getting the ImagePullBackOff error for one of my containers. I have verified that the image exists in my container registry and that the credentials are correct.

Could you help me understand what might be causing this error? I have already checked registry permissions and credentials, but I cannot resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

**Dockerfile:**

```
    //build command:  docker build -t my-simple-app .

    FROM node:alpine
    ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY package*.json ./
    RUN npm install
    COPY . .
    EXPOSE 3000
    CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**kubectl get pods:**

```
react-app-deployment-7854bbdb98-c4gzf   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          17s
react-app-deployment-7854bbdb98-dvzls   0/1     ErrImagePull       0          17s
react-app-deployment-7854bbdb98-vb7pm   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          17s
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: react-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: react-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: react-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: react-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: react-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: react-app-container
          image: my-simple-app  # Use the image name and tag you built earlier
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000  # Adjust the port as needed
```

Comment: There is more information to the right in the `kubectl get pods` output that may be informative.  I'd normally expect the `image:` to look like `registry.example.com/my-simple-app` or similar, telling the cluster where to find the image; does it have this form, or is your image hosted on Docker Hub?

Answer (score 0):

ImagePullBackOff maens your conatiner is trying to pull the image from your registry.But it couldn't due to the following reasons 1.Check your credentials of your registry and mount that credential in deplloyment through secret or configmap 2.ensure that particular image exist in your registry and have given that path correctly in deployment file

Answer (score 0):

I guess your cluster is not properly configured with the ACR.

use this documentation to connect the existing ACR with the cluster, otherwise you have to delete the cluster and, configure the ACR when creating cluster.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration?tabs=azure-cli#create-a-new-aks-cluster-and-integrate-with-an-existing-acr